# AUR package cannot be built and installed - what to do?

Tags: arch-linux, compiling, pacman, manjaro, aur

AUR is said the largest repository out there but sometimes, when trying to build and install, and also to build and install dependencies, the outcome is not always a success.

What a medium user can do at that point?

Normally (that is, for a ubuntu user) , the idea is to build and install from source. That is temerary enough endeavour for me - but how can I try to fix what the automated Pamac/pacman could not?

Comment: I don't think "temerary" is a word, but I'm not sure what you meant instead.

Comment: @FaheemMitha - It is a word (although not in the Firefox dic), but it's an adjective, and therefore I will change the phrase: it means rash, reckless -  what I meant was *reckless for one like me to try to* etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The AUR is an unsupported repository: the quality of the PKGBUILDS varies from the very good through to the abominably bad or outright negligent.

You should *always* **read the PKGBUILD before attempting to install anything** and look at the comments on the package page to satisfy yourself that there won't be any unforseen "surprises" when running `makepkg`.

You should also *not* get in the habit of relying on an AUR helper to automate the build process for you and thereby blur the distinction between the officially supported repositories and the AUR.

If a particular PKGBUILD does not build successfully, the first step is to try and build it manually: `makepkg` will provide meaningful error messages that should provide sufficient information to identify the issue.

Arch Linux is not like Ubuntu: users are expected to be able to read PKGBUILDs (basic bash scripts, essentially) and the `man` page for `makepkg` and understand the build process sufficiently to responsibly maintain their installations.

If the fault lies with the PKGBUILD, leave a comment to that effect on the package's AUR page to alert the maintainer and anyone else who may want to install the same package. If the  issue goes unaddressed, you can always ask to have the package orphaned, then adopt it and fix the PKGBUILD so that it works as expected.

There are [guidelines for maintaining packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Maintaining_packages) on the Arch Wiki.

Comment: Aren't pamac/pacman/yaourt using the same process `makepkg` that I would when building manually? And aren't there displayed the same meaningful error messages?

Comment: @cipricus pacman is not involved at all in building AUR packages (it installs the built package). AUR helpers, like Pamac and Yaourt, each have their own quirks that may or may not mask diagnostic issues. The point is, if there is a problem with the build, the only *guaranteed* way to debug it is to build it manually.